# Checking if 2 of 3 string is null to do something in razor/c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a tabbed image and tittle i want to show and hide based on if images exist or not. There are 3 images and 3 title, i am already hiding titles if images for each of those are empty (see code). Now i have a new requirement , Hide all titles if only 1 of 3 image exist. BTW i am checking if image exist via checking "src" exist ( which is a string).

So I know i can check if all of the strings are empty like this

```
bool allNull = strings.All(s => s == null);
```

But how do i check if 2 of 3 images/string is empty?

**My current solution is a simple counter then using jquery to remove titles, which works great but i want to know if there is a c#/razor answer (in cshtml file)**

```
<div class="tabbed-images pt-25 pt-sm-50 pb-sm-25">
<div class="header">
    @{
        int counter = 0;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.BasicLevelImage.Src))
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            <div class="tab-item active bg-pl-basic">@Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("PackageFeatureLevelBasic")</div>
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProfessionalLevelImage.Src))
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            <div class="tab-item bg-pl-professional">@Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("PackageFeatureLevelProfessional")</div>
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PremiumLevelImage.Src))
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            <div class="tab-item bg-pl-premium">@Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("PackageFeatureLevelPremium")</div>
        }

        if (counter < 2)
        {
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    $(".tabbed-images .header").remove();                      
                    }); 
            </script>
        }
    }

</div>
<div class="image-container">
    @Html.Glass().Editable(x => x.BasicLevelImage, new { @class = "resp-img active" })
    @Html.Glass().Editable(x => x.ProfessionalLevelImage, new { @class = "resp-img" })
    @Html.Glass().Editable(x => x.PremiumLevelImage, new { @class = "resp-img" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool allNull = strings.Count(s => s == null) == 2;
```